# How to implement ScrollEventHandler

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

I am trying to implement the `ScrollEventHandler` and I keep getting the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventHandler' to 'System.EventHandler'

Here is my code:

```
zoomBar.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(this.zoomBar_Scroll);
```

And here is the method:

```
private void zoomBar_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {

            if ( e.OldValue > e.NewValue)
            {

                wChart.zoomMinus();

            }
            else
            {

                wChart.zoomPlus();
            }

        }
```

I think this matches exactly what is in the Microsoft documentation but I must be missing something.

Here is a screenshot of the metadata for scroll

[image]

Comment: what type is a `zoomBar`?

Comment: zoomBar is simply the name of my scrollbar. I use the scroll bar to zoom in and out on a chart.

Comment: Something else is wonky here; the code as given seems to match exactly the code generated by the forms designer when attaching to the Scroll event of a VScrollBar. Drop a brand new V/HScrollBar on a form and double click on it, then Find All references on the generated click event handler; is it the same as your code? Does it work when the designer does it?

Comment: If you add it from the designer you get zoomBar.Scroll += new System.EventHandler(this.zoombar_Scroll). The difference is you get System.EventHandler instead of ScrollEventHandler. The method declaration from the designer is private void zoomBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e). Again the difference being that you get EventArgs instead of ScrollEventArgs. This does work and it will fire for the scroll event but e.OldValue and e.NewValue only exist in ScrollEventArgs not in EventArgs.

Comment: What version of .net are you using/what platform/what VStudio? I tested in netfw 472 and net6 and my designer made ScrollEventArgs in each case.. plus SEA has been around nearly forever as far as I can see..

Comment: If you right click on the word Scroll you have written in code and choose "go to definition", what class opens? Put a screenshot of the metadata for the event and the comment lines at the top of the meta that say the assembly etc

Comment: I am using .net 4.7.2 and VS Community 2019 (16.11.7)

Comment: I think I see where I have went wrong and I have to a apologize. I have been saying scrollbar and I should have been saying TrackBar. Sorry I was working on something else and the terminology stuck in my head.ScrollEventArgs goes with Scrollbar.

Comment: There's a mistake in the documentation. The TrackBar is listed among the Controls that makes use of a  [ScrollEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrolleventhandler) delegate, but it's not correct. -- Just store the current value and compare with the next value in `ValueChanged`, if necessary.

Comment: I was just looking at that again and yes there does seem to be a mistake there. I feel a little bit better that I am not completely losing my mind, only partially. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: TrackBar.Scroll documentation is correct. Have filed an issue to have ScrollEventHandler documentation corrected. If there is ever an argument between what VS Intellisense/compiler tells you versus documentation, compiler wins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the scrollbar event and the trackbar event confused. `ScrollEventsArgs` goes with `ScrollBar` not `TrackBar`. But as someone pointed out in the comments there is a mistake in the documentation that indicates `ScrollEventsArgs` works with `TrackBar` but it does not.

Here is a link to the documentation.

[ScrollEventHandlerDelegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrolleventhandler?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
zoomBar.Scroll += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.OldValue > e.NewValue)
    {
        wChart.zoomMinus();
    }
    else
    {
        wChart.zoomPlus();
    }
};
```

Comment: This does work but with the same problem shown in my comment about e.OldValue and e.NewValue only exist in ScrollEventArgs